# Linear transformation that must not be an isomorphism

Tags: linear-transformations

I am a bit lost on this one:

Let $a$ and $b$ be linearly independent vectors and $T: \mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3$ the transformation given by the rule:

$$T(x)=x-(b\cdot x)a,$$

where $b\cdot x$ is the dot product. Find $a$ and $b$ for which the transformation $T$ is **not** an isomorphism.

Comment: It should probably be "... For which the transformation T is not *an isomorphism*", meaning it's either not injective or not surjective. Does this clarify the problem for you or are you stuck in some other place?

Comment: You need to find an $x$ so that $Tx=0$, so yo need $x=(b\cdot x)a$.

Answer (score 1):

You need $x\neq 0$ with $Tx=0$. Then $Tx=0$ if and only if $x=(b\cdot x)a$. But that means that $x$ is a scalar multiple of $a$, and since $T$ is linear, that means $Ta=0$. Work from there.